# Proving $6 \sec\phi \tan\phi = \frac{3}{1-\sin\phi} - \frac{3}{1+\sin \phi}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> $$6 \sec\phi \tan\phi = \frac{3}{1-\sin\phi} - \frac{3}{1+\sin \phi}$$

I can't seem to figure out how to prove this.

Whenever I try to prove the left side, I end up with $\frac{6\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, which I think might be right.

As for the right side, I get confused with the denominators and what to do with them. I know if I square root  $1-\sin\phi$, I'll get a Pythagorean identity, but then I don't know where to go from there.

Please help me with a step-by-step guide. I really want to learn how to do this.

Comment: Clearing denominators is apt to simplify this particular problem, but there is more than one approach to simplification.

Comment: For the RHS, how do you get a common denominator? Hint: find $$\frac{3}{5}-\frac{3}{7}$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\sec \phi\tan\phi &= \frac{\sin \phi}{\cos^2\phi}\\
&=\frac{\sin\phi}{1-\sin^2\phi}\\
&=\frac{\sin\phi}{(1+\sin\phi)(1-\sin\phi)}\\
&=\sin\phi\cdot \frac{1}{2\sin \phi} \left(\frac{1}{1-\sin\phi}-\frac{1}{1+\sin\phi}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{1-\sin\phi}-\frac{1}{1+\sin\phi}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Notice that 
$$\frac{3}{1-\sin\phi} - \frac{3}{1+\sin \phi}=\frac{3+3\sin\phi-3+3\sin\phi}{1-\sin^{2}\phi}$$
using $1-\sin^2\phi=\cos^2 \phi$,
We get 
$$\frac{6\sin \phi}{\cos^2 \phi}=\frac{6\sin \phi}{(\cos \phi)(\cos \phi)}$$
$$6\sec \phi \tan \phi$$

Comment: but why would you cross multiply to get the numerator of 3+3....

Comment: @Esma - to add two fractions together, they need to have a common denominator. The smallest common denominator in this case is their product. So $$\frac 3{1 - \sin \phi} = \frac 3{1 - \sin \phi}\frac {1 + \sin \phi}{1 + \sin \phi} = \frac {3(1+\sin \phi)}{1 - \sin^2 \phi}$$ and $$\frac 3{1 + \sin \phi} = \frac 3{1 + \sin \phi}\frac {1 - \sin \phi}{1 - \sin \phi} = \frac {3(1-\sin \phi)}{1 - \sin^2 \phi}$$

Comment: @Esma : You start with one term on the left and two terms on the right.  At some point, you're going to have to cancel or merge the terms on the right.  One way to do this is putting them over a common denominator.  (Nothing was [cross-multiplied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication).  That term only applies to multiplication *across* an equals sign.  The two fractions were put over a common denominator.)

Comment: thank you so much. I understand now. This is what I did at first, but got lost. Once again, thank you so much for your help @PaulSinclair

Answer (score 2):

We have: $$\textbf{RHS} = \dfrac{3(1+\sin \phi)-3(1-\sin \phi)}{(1-\sin \phi)(1+\sin \phi)}= \dfrac{3+3\sin \phi-3+3\sin \phi}{1-\sin^2\phi}\\ =\dfrac{6\sin \phi}{\cos^2\phi}= 6\cdot \dfrac{\sin \phi}{\cos \phi}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\cos \phi}= 6\tan\phi\sec\phi= \textbf{LHS}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\hspace{-3cm}\begin{align*}
\frac{3}{1-\sin\phi} - \frac{3}{1+\sin \phi} &= \frac{(3+3 \sin \phi) - (3 - 3 \sin \phi)}{1-\sin ^2 \phi} \tag{common denominator}\\
&= \frac{6 \sin \phi}{\cos^2 \phi} \tag{Pythagorean identity} \\
&= 6 \left ( \frac{\sin \phi}{\cos \phi} \right ) \left ( \frac{1}{\cos \phi} \right ) \\
&= 6 \sec \phi \tan \phi
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Just for notice - you can use align environment without adding "$$" tags.

Comment: How do I align left? In my browser my equation tags are overlapping with hot network posts.

Comment: You can "add" negative horizontal space before the aligned environment. Iv'e edited your post, adding negative horizontal space of 3 cm. You might edit it to your satisfaction.

Comment: This is not [cross multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication).  Cross multiplication is multiplying across an equals sign, which is not what is being demonstrated.  What you have done is put your fractions over a common denominator.

Comment: @Eric Towers Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As $(1-\sin\phi)(1+\sin\phi)=\cos^2\phi,$

$$\dfrac1{1\pm\sin\phi}=\dfrac{1\mp\sin\phi}{\cos^2\phi}=\sec^2\phi\mp\sec\phi\tan\phi$$

Answer (score 1):

You can do this either from LHS to RHS or from RHS to LHS.
**Solution 1:** LHS $\rightarrow$ RHS
$$\require{cancel}\begin{aligned}6\sec\phi\tan\phi&=6\frac{1}{\cos\phi}\frac{\sin\phi}{\cos\phi}\\&=\frac{6\sin\phi}{\cos^2\phi}\\&=\frac{3\sin\phi+3\sin\phi}{\left(1-\sin\phi\right)\left(1+\sin\phi\right)}\\&=\frac{3\left(1+\sin\phi\right)-3\left(1-\sin\phi\right)}{\left(1-\sin\phi\right)\left(1+\sin\phi\right)}\\&=\frac{3\cancel{\left(1+\sin\phi\right)}}{\left(1-\sin\phi\right)\cancel{\left(1+\sin\phi\right)}}-\frac{3\cancel{\left(1-\sin\phi\right)}}{\cancel{\left(1-\sin\phi\right)}\left(1+\sin\phi\right)}\\&=\frac{3}{1-\sin\phi}-\frac{3}{1+\sin\phi}\end{aligned}$$
**Solution 2:** RHS $\rightarrow$ LHS
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{3}{1-\sin\phi}-\frac{3}{1+\sin\phi}&=\frac{3\left(1+\sin\phi\right)-3\left(1-\sin\phi\right)}{\left(1-\sin\phi\right)\left(1+\sin\phi\right)}\\&=\frac{\cancel3+3\sin\phi\cancel{-3}+3\sin\phi}{\left(1-\sin\phi\right)\left(1+\sin\phi\right)}\\&=\frac{6\sin\phi}{1-\sin^2\phi}\\&=\frac{6\sin\phi}{\cos^2\phi}\\&=\frac{6\sin\phi}{\cos\phi\cos\phi}\\&=6\sec\phi\tan\phi\end{aligned}$$
I hope this helps.